# Serving shared images in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image, asp.net-web-api

I'm working on a project that involves two web portals hosted on the same IIS 7.5 server:
(A) MVC4 web application for administration
(B) Mobile MVC4 web application with jQuery Mobile

Both are retrieving the data from the Web API based services hosted on other IIS server.

Now I'm about to add manipulation of images that are managed on Admin portal (A) and displayed to clients within Mobile app (B). Images will be added/changed dynamically with higher frequency.

I had two solutions in my mind:

1. Store all images in database on the server that hosts Web API as byte arrays, and send them on demand as base64 strings - render them on mobile app pages as base64 strings:

   - Can set any kind of security restrictions and integrate them well with MVC
   - Pages would be rendered in one request
   - Transferring from Web API to Mobile app
   - What happens to caching?
2. Store all images on the server that hosts both (A) and (B) in some shared folder, include them in rendered pages as regular  tags.

   - No transfer between WebAPI and Web server
   - Caching of images
   - Several requests for each image on the page

Thing that I have to take in consideration as well is that there will be native iPhone app that will do the same role as mobile web app, meaning it should have access to same set of images.

Any thoughts would be appreciated on this, I'm looking for best practices solution, a guide, hints, or anything that I could use.

Also, if option 2. is suggested, what is the best place to store images to be shared between two portals?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you going with option 2 and store the images on some shared folder. The best would be to have a specific application that will act as CDN hosting all your static resources. According to [YSlow best practices](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html) this CDN should be hosted on a different top level domain than the clients, thus allowing cookieless access to those lowering the bandwidth consumption.